# How to register TypeVar using catts register_structure_hook?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python3.11 and cattrs==23.1.2
I have registered

```
from typing import (
    Tuple,
    TypeVar,
)

Number = TypeVar('Number', int, float)
```

and the try to register as Converter

```
converter = cattr.Converter()
converter.register_structure_hook(Number, _value_to_number)
```

And my error is :

```
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid first argument to `register()`. ~Number is not a class or union type.
```